# Issue about musdb package

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to use MUSDB dataset. However, I got the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home3/will/BandSplitRNN-Pytorch-main/src/123.py", line 5, in 
mus = musdb.DB(root="/home3/will/musdb18")
File "/home3/will/anaconda3/envs/MUSDB/lib/python3.10/site-packages/musdb/**init**.py", line 115, in **init**
self.tracks = self.load_mus_tracks(subsets=subsets, split=split)
File "/home3/will/anaconda3/envs/MUSDB/lib/python3.10/site-packages/musdb/**init**.py", line 256, in load_mus_tracks
track = MultiTrack(
File "/home3/will/anaconda3/envs/MUSDB/lib/python3.10/site-packages/musdb/audio_classes.py", line 133, in **init**
super(MultiTrack, self).**init**(path=path, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home3/will/anaconda3/envs/MUSDB/lib/python3.10/site-packages/musdb/audio_classes.py", line 52, in **init**
self.info = stempeg.Info(self.path)
File "/home3/will/anaconda3/envs/MUSDB/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stempeg/read.py", line 328, in **init**
self.info = ffmpeg.probe(filename)
File "/home3/will/anaconda3/envs/MUSDB/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ffmpeg/_probe.py", line 23, in probe
raise Error('ffprobe', out, err)
ffmpeg._run.Error: ffprobe error (see stderr output for detail)

I do have downloaded the dataset, and I also have installed ffmpeg and musdb in my virtual env, but I still cannot use the data.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
pip install --upgrade musdb
pip install --upgrade stempeg
```